# Running several MS Access macros in separate databases asynchronously

Tags: vba, batch-file, ms-access, cmd

I have 4 MS Access Databases that each have the same exact macro written into them. The macros take about 4 hours to run, and I want to set them up so they will run when I am not at work.

I envision my batch file to look something like this:

```
msaccess.exe /ro "c:\Folder1\DB1.accdb" /x MyMacro
msaccess.exe /ro "c:\Folder2\DB2.accdb" /x MyMacro
msaccess.exe /ro "c:\Folder3\DB3.accdb" /x MyMacro
msaccess.exe /ro "c:\Folder4\DB4.accdb" /x MyMacro
```

However, I only want the next line to start when the current line is completely finished. Is there a way to control this?

I went with the START /WAIT command. I had to modify MyMacro to have MS Access close down after each run, but it worked like a charm. Thanks everyone!

Comment: This, "*I only want the next line to start when the current line is completely finished*" is called synchronous, not asynchronous.  And it's the normal mode that a script or procedure will run in, so you shouldn't have to change anything.

Comment: RBarryYoung - Your statement about running scripts synchronously by default is only true of built-in commands and/or terminal programs.  It is not true of normal Windows UI programs.  In this case, MS Access is started, but execution control is immediately returned to the script while MS Access is still running and any macro that was started.  Why do people vote up such comments without testing and/or having certain knowledge?

Comment: @CPerkins - The OP mentioned `my batch file` which probably implies `cmd.exe` processing.

Comment: Try to precede every line with `start "" /WAIT`...

Comment: {Slap forehead} Thanks lit. I voted up RBarryYoung's comment. I had manually typed my test batch file and out of habit had typed "start" (without \WAIT or any other options) before all my calls to Access which prevents it from blocking.  I didn't realize what I'd done until aschipfl posted his comment.

Comment: @RBarryYoung. Well it's synchronous in that it will execute line by line yes, but once the cmd kicks off the MS Access Macro, then it will move on to the next line. I want the the cmd to wait until AFTER the macro is complete, which is around 4 hours. I want the next line to be a sort of callback function when the current line finishes.

But it looks like start \wait is going to be my solution. I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in the past using VBS, save the file as .vbs and then use Task Scheduler to run it at a certain time. This will work with Subs and Functions. Please see vbs code below, you will just need to add 2 more sections to bring it a total of 4 databases.

```
dim accessApp
set accessApp = createObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.visible = false
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase("Database Path Here")
accessApp.Run "Sub or Function Name Here"
accessApp.Quit
set accessApp = nothing

dim accessApp2
set accessApp2 = createObject("Access.Application")
accessApp2.visible = false
accessApp2.OpenCurrentDataBase("Database Path Here")
accessApp2.Run "Sub or Function Name Here"
accessApp2.Quit
set accessApp2 = nothing
```

Comment: Use a loop. What if there are 100 databases?

Answer (score 0):

This script will run on each of the databases in `DB_LIST` and stop if there is an error. Is this the kind of thing you are looking for?

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "DB_LIST=DB1 DB2 DB3 DB4"

FOR %%d IN (%DB_LIST%) DO (
    msaccess.exe /ro "c:\Folder4\%%~d.accdb" /x MyMacro
    SET EXITCODE=%ERRORLEVEL%
    IF !EXITCODE! NEQ 0 (
        ECHO ERROR: Failed in %0 running database %%~f, EXITCODE is !EXITCODE!
        GOTO TheEnd
    )
)

:TheEnd
EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with the START /WAIT command. I had to modify MyMacro to have MS Access close down after each run, but it worked like a charm. Thanks everyone!

My code ended up looking something like this:

```
START /WAIT msaccess.exe /ro "c:\Folder1\DB1.accdb" /x MyMacro
START /WAIT msaccess.exe /ro "c:\Folder2\DB2.accdb" /x MyMacro
START /WAIT msaccess.exe /ro "c:\Folder3\DB3.accdb" /x MyMacro
START /WAIT msaccess.exe /ro "c:\Folder4\DB4.accdb" /x MyMacro
```